# How to apply bootstrap <a> style to a <button> in a navbar

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Bootstrap's CSS automatically applies a nice look to `<a>` tags when inside an `<li>` inside a `<nav class="navbar-nav">`. I needed this nice look on a clickable `<a>` tag with `href="#"` that executes some javascript.

However i'm also using React, which throws warnings ([see here](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md)) when an `<a>` tag has an href of `#`. So according to [this](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md):

> However, we understand that developers are not always in total control of the visual design of web applications. In cases where it is imperative to provide an element resembling an anchor that purely acts as a click target with no navigation as result, we would like to recommend a compromise.
>
> Again change the element to a <button>:

```
<button 
  type="button"
  className="link-button" 
  onClick={() => this.setState({showSomething: true})}>
    Press me, I look like a link
</button>
```

> Then use styling to change its appearance to that of a link:

```
.link-button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.link-button:hover,
.link-button:focus {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

That would work, except Bootstrap doesn't apply the CSS to it anymore. Do I need to manually add the CSS to the button, or am I missing something?

It seems the way to do it is to just add the CSS to the button, but i'm not sure. Is there, for example, a way to make buttons with a specific class function exactly like `<a>`s (in terms of CSS)?

Comment: Can't you just use `#1`?

Comment: @Paulie_D what `#1`? For the href attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to make a button look like a link, you can do something like this:

```css
.link-like {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,.5) !important;
}

.link-like:hover {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.7) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <button class="nav-link btn-outline-light border-0 link-like ">Imposter</button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link">True Anchor</a>
      </li>
    </ul>    
  </div>
</nav>
```

You can remove stuff like borders and backgrounds using some of bootstrap's classes and one of your own. This is how it works:

- `btn-outline-light` will give the button a white background and text color
- `border-0` removes the borders of the button
- `link-like` reproduces the other properties of a typical anchor element such as: background, normal and hover states

here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/rQzBmg) :)

On the other hand, there's also a `btn-link` class according to [bootstrap 3.0.3's documentation](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/css/#buttons)  which I believe react-bootstrap (since its in the tags) targets.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there, for example, a way to make buttons with a specific class function exactly like s (in terms of CSS)

Yes, why no.

just create some `css` class in some global scope and put there all the styles you need.

e.g.:

```
// in your css/scss file
.myLink {
  // same css what bootstrap applies
}

// then just use it whenever you need in JSX:
<button className="myLink">...</button>
```